# What forms (S-1, 8-K, etc) and keywords in news headlines signify dilution?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-analysis, stock-valuation, warrants

I'm trying to create a program to scan a news RSS feed for stocks that are in the process of getting diluted so that I do filter the market down to a few stocks and then do extra research on them.

My program will look for keywords in the news. Right now I only have keywords like `cashless exercise, warrant, form s-1`. Are there any keywords (like certain forms, etc) that signify a future drop in price that you feel would be useful?

An example would be GBSN (https://www.google.com/finance?q=gbsn&ei=MHYRVtDVPMKVmAHopJKgBA). In January it filed `Form S-1` which showed up on the news. It said warrants wouldn't be exercised until 6 months later and right at the date that the S-1 said it could be exercised (in July) it dropped.

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibles: stock offering, secondary placement, increase authorized number of shares, shelf registration.

Comment: thanks michael. FYI using those key words (took out stock offering) i got: "APPS", "AUPH", "CELGZ", "CERE", "CTIC", "IFON", "MNKD", "MSLI", "RBCN" if you were curious